# Map is not visible in my app.its looking grey color

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi i am using maps activity.At first,in my app map is shown while debugging but not shown after publishing.Then i searched and find a method to find a sha1 finger print for release mode and generated APIkey to rectify this problem.i tried so many times genearting api key  and changes package name and tried again.Now its not visible even in debug and also in release.anybody please help me.i am getting error as follows

`Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-02 05:23:19.987 10640-11587/taxicall.notebook.taxicall E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                     Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                     Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                        API Key: AIzaSyDOLRqaimoDk-*****;
                                                                                        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 70:1D:3C:06:72:FF:8B:C0:93:*********;taxicall.******`

Comment: Are you following the google guide ? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: @fabina valencia ..thankyou for ur reply....In that developers guide,the extension of keystore is written as .keystore but i am getting .jks.Is there any problem in that?

Comment: i am getting above error,but the fingerprint key present there is my debug key not release key.i generated maps api key with another fingerprint key generated in release mode.

Comment: .jks means Java Keystore. I dont think thats the problem, I think your mixing up the release and debug key. I will try to look for a good refference tu give you.

Comment: In your  console.developers.google.com  are you sure the google maps api is enabled ? 
go to Api Manager--> Library --> enable maps api for your project.